# Flow complains about untyped import

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, flowtype

I'm starting out on a React Native project that uses [`react-native-geolocation-service`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service) to get the user's GPS location, but Flow is complaining that the library is untyped. The library has Typescript types, but doesn't seem to have Flow types, and VS Code gives me this error when I import the library.

> Importing from an untyped module makes it `any` and is not safe! Did you mean to add `// @flow` to the top of `react-native-geolocation-service`? (`untyped-import`)Flow(LintError-untyped-import)

Can I convince Flow to stop complaining about this library, or should I switch to Typescript? I don't have any particular preference for Flow, it's just what `react-native init` set up for me.

I used this to create the project:

```
npx react-native init WarmerWalker
```

Then I added the library like this:

```
npm install react-native-geolocation-service
```

I import the library like this in my [`App.js`](https://github.com/donkirkby/warmer-walker/blob/d440f1dcc22116a67ac285925c58ff5cd1325999/App.js#L28):

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
```

I tried adding the library to the [untyped section](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/untyped/) in `.flowconfig`, but that didn't help. Neither did the `ignore` section.

The code seems to work, it's just making Flow complain.

Comment: Are you using flow in [strict mode](https://flow.org/en/docs/strict/)?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a comment from Alex, I learned about [strict mode](https://flow.org/en/docs/strict/). The sample app that `react-native` created used [`@flow strict-local`](https://github.com/donkirkby/warmer-walker/blob/d440f1dcc22116a67ac285925c58ff5cd1325999/App.js#L6), so that was causing the problem. Removing `strict-local` made it stop complaining.

However, since the library I want to use has Typescript type definitions, I'm going to switch to Typescript. I regenerated the sample app with the [Typescript template](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript), like this:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Comment: It usually doesn't matter what flavour of type checker a library is written in. You can always add the types using the definitions repo. https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed in this case. Though no one has typed `react-native-geolocation-service` yet so you'd get any until you or someone else does this.